# Link to Home page from another page with sub page anchor (i.e. /#somebookmark)

Tags: html

I'm trying to do something that I thought would be really simple but I can't make it work.

My bookmark anchors work fine if I'm on the home page but the same links in the header of my page don't work if the # part refers to the home page:

```
<a href="/#somesubanchor">Some Link Text</a>
```

It works if I have some sort of page name, but doesn't work for the home page. (i.e. this works: `<a href="/home/index#somesubanchor">Some Link Text</a>`)

Of course if the href is just / it works fine.

So how the heck does one link to a bookmark in the home page from another page?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand...the "home page" is usually just a regular file e.g. `index.html` mapped to `/`. Hence, `http://mydomain.com` or `http://mydomain.com/` or `http://mydomain.com/index.html` usually return the same content. This configuration goes by the terms 'welcome file' or [directory index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webserver_directory_index). Specific for the Apache webserver: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings Hence, you need to know the name of your "home page file" (`index.html`, `index.php`, ...) and link directly to it.

Comment: Ya, but as soon as you link to it from another page and put a #<somesubanchor> it fails. This works: <a href="/">text</a> this does not: <a href="/#SomeSubAnchor">text</a>  note the bookmark/sub anchor. As soon as you do this with the / it fails and won't redirect back to the home page and just sits there looking for the #SomeSubAnchor on the current page. It does however work fine if you specify a real page instead of just / but then you break SEO.

Comment: I believe I did/do understand the problem. However, I fail to understand why you think '/' is so special. Just _use_ the real resource that's mapped (by convenience) behind '/'. Don't see how this should break SEO.

Comment: It's so special because the search engine lands on http://www.somedomain.com/. If you then use http://www.somedomain.com/index.html in other places, the search engine interprets it as a second page and you use your link juice because you've split it between 2 pages. Worse, google thinks that you're stuffing and down scores you for duplicate content.

Comment: Is this behavior specific to your OS/browser? The following link works fine in Safari/Firefox/Chrome on OS X: http://frightanic.com/#categories-2 (browser scrolls to the 'Categories' sidebar widget).

Comment: Does it on Safari, Firefox, Chrome and IE. The difference between yours and mine is that you're specifying the domain etc. I'm not. I'm using /#categories-2 and that's it because it has to be relative so that we don't have issues on deploy to production.

Comment: Doesn't make the slightest difference in Safari/Firefox/Chrome on OS X. Test bed: http://frightanic.com/misc/linkwithanchor.html.

Comment: Since you're talking about < 5% of all computers, I'm not really concerned about those. I'm concerned about the other 95% running on Windows PCs that don't work.

Comment: This is starting to annoy me. Now got my hands on a Windows PC. http://frightanic.com/misc/linkwithanchor.html works just as fine in FF/IE9 on Win 7 as it does on OS X. I'm out...

Comment: You missed the point. Put a link on a second page like this l: <a href="/#fire">link</a>. It won't work. Confirmed it doesn't work in any browser including ios.  Thus as far as I can tell there is no seo friendly way to link to a bookmark on the homepage aliased as / with a bookmark.  I'm seeking confirmation or a way to do it. Nothing more.  But its key that you put this on a second page. It works fine from the homepage itself.